# how to savedInstanceState a Marker objects in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, marker

I'm confused about how to properly save a Marker objects in my onSaveInstanceState() method. I have read that I will need to implement the Parcelable class for my object, but I am still a bit lost on the actual implementation. Has anyone had any experience with this who might be able to provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marker object does not implement the Parcelable interface and it cannot be directly saved into Bundle. However, you are free to save relevant data to those markers (lat-lng values for example) and to rebuild markers when the application is resumed.

To answer your question: You cannot save markers directly and you probably should not, but you can save relevant objects which implement Parcelable.